Prove a property of constructible numbers while reproducing Landau's proof for the impossibility of doubling the cube
I've been reading John Stillwell's Mathematics and Its History (3rd edition) and came across the famous geometric construction problem: doubling the cube. Pierre Wantzel in 1837 proved that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not a constructible number, hence it is impossible to double a cube using a straightedge and compass. In Chapter 6 of this book, Stillwell wrote that Edmund Landau (1877-1938) found an elementary proof that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not constructible when he was still a student. The original proof of Landau is nowhere found in the book or the Internet, but it is broken down into simple steps as exercises, I quote:

6.4.1 Show that the assumption $\sqrt[3]{2} = m/n$, where $m$ and $n$ are integers, leads to a contradiction.
Landau's proof now organizes all numbers involved in a construction into sets $F_{0}, F_{1}, F_{2}, \ldots$ according to the "depth of nesting" of square roots.
6.4.2 Let
$$ F_{0} = \mathbb{Q}, F_{k+1} = \{ a + b\sqrt{c_{k}}: a, b\in F_{k} \}\quad \text{for some $c_{k}\in F_{k}$} $$
Show that each $F_{k}$ is a field, that is, if $x, y$ are in $F_{k}$, then so are $x + y, x - y, xy,$ and $x/y$ (for $y\ne 0$).
We know from Exercise 6.4.1 that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not in $F_{0}$, but if it is constructible it will occur in some $F_{k+1}$. A contradiction now ensues in considering (hypothetically) the first such $F_{k+1}$.
6.4.3 Show that if $a, b, c\in F_{k}$ but $\sqrt{c}\notin F_{k}$, then $a + b\sqrt{c} = 0 \Leftrightarrow a = b = 0$ (For $k = 0$ this is in the Elements, Book X, Prop. 79.)
6.4.4 Suppose $\sqrt[3]{2} = a + b\sqrt{c}$, where $a, b, c\in F_{k}$, but that $\sqrt[3]{2}\notin F_{k}$ (We know that $\sqrt[3]{2}\notin F_{0}$ from Exercise 6.4.1.) Cube both sides and deduce from Exercise 6.4.3 that
$$ 2 = a^{3} + 3ab^{2}c \quad\text{ and }\quad 0 = 3a^{2}b + b^{3}c $$
6.4.5 Deduce from Exercise 6.4.4 that $\sqrt[3]{2} = a - b\sqrt{c}$ also, and explain why this is a contradiction.

I've followed these exercises and had no problem solving them: 6.4.1 is similar to proving $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, 6.4.2 is like a routine exercise where one must verify every field axiom, 6.4.3 can be proved by contradiction, 6.4.4 and 6.4.5 lead to the final contradiction from which we can conclude $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not constructible.
I saw that the core idea behind the proof is the following result (I made up its name).

Constructibility Theorem. For every real number $r$, $r$ is constructible if and only if there is a list of fields $F_{0}, F_{1}, \ldots, F_{n}$ (as in Exercise 6.4.2) such that $r\in F_{n}$.

Hence for a real number $x$, if there is no such list then $x$ isn't constructible. The constructibility theorem is quite intuitive if one knows a number is constructible if and only if it can be expressed in closed form with only rational numbers and the following operations: addition (subtraction), multiplication (division), and square root. This fact can be explained by showing that geometric constructions (given the origin and point $(1, 0)$ in 2D Cartesian) involve solving systems of linear/quadratic equations (with two unknowns).
For example, let's consider $r = 2 + \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5}}$, we determine a list of fields as follows:

$c_{0} = 5$, $F_{1} = \{ a + b\sqrt{5}: a, b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$
$c_{1} = 3 + \sqrt{5}$, $F_{2} = \{ a + b\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5}}: a, b\in F_{1} \}$
So $r \in F_{2}$

The $\Longleftarrow$ part (constructible $\Longleftarrow$ the existence of a list of fields) follows from the fact that a number is constructible if and only if it admits a closed-form expression using only rational numbers and finitely many times of allowed operations.
I am interested in finding a proof for the $\implies$ part (constructible $\implies$ the existence of a list of fields) as it is not trivial. In the spirit of Landau's proof, I want to find proof for the constructibility theorem with minimal prerequisites, without using the theory of field extensions (the degree of a field extension, to be precise).

A high-school student should be able to understand the following proof if he/she is introduced to the definition of a field and a constructible number.
Proof. We prove a fine-tuned version of the constructibility theorem

Given a finite set $C$ of constructible numbers. Prove that there exists a list of fields $F_{0}, F_{1}, \ldots, F_{n}$ (as Exercise 6.4.2) such that $C$ is contained in $F_{n}$.

We use strong mathematical induction on the nonnegative integer $m$ where every constructible number in the given finite set can be expressed by using only rational numbers and no more than $m$ times of allowed operations (addition, multiplication, and taking square root). For example, $C = \{ 1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} \}$, then $m$ is at least $3$.
Paragraphs in italics like this are where I explain the idea of this proof.
The base case (using no operations). In this case, every element of $C$ is rational and they belong to $F_{0}$.
Suppose that the statement is true for finite sets of constructible numbers that each element's expression uses only rational numbers and less than $m$ times of allowed operations.
We will show that if a finite set $C$ of constructible numbers that the expressions of these numbers contain only rational numbers and use no more than $m$ times of allowed operations then there is a list of fields $F_{0}, F_{1}, \ldots, F_{n}$ such that $C$ is contained in $F_{n}$.
Observe that in an expression, like $\sqrt{7} + 2 + \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5}}$, perform the operations in the following order:

(a) take square root of 7
(b) add it to 2
(c) take the square root of 5
(d) add the result from (c) to 3
(e) take the square root of the result from (d)
(f) add the result from (b) to the result from (e)

That is, if we perform the operations from left to right and of course obey the order of operations. The order of operations of an expression (not number) is uniquely determined. So if the expression contains operations, it has a last operation. For example, the last operation of $\sqrt{7} + 2 + \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5}}$ is addition, that of $\sqrt{2}$ is square root, that of $\frac{6}{7}\sqrt{11}$ and $-\sqrt{2} = (-1)\cdot\sqrt{2}$ is multiplication. At this point, one might argue that $C$ should be defined as a finite set of closed-form expressions instead of a finite set of constructible numbers - I agree with that. For every number in $C$, we have already chosen a fixed expression (using only rational numbers and finitely many times of allowed operations) for it.
Note that, in Exercise 6.4.2, $F_{0} \subseteq F_{1} \subseteq F_{2} \subseteq \cdots$
Case 1. The last operation of every number in $C$ is either addition or multiplication.
Denote by $\left\vert C\right\vert$ the number of elements of $C$.
In this case, for every $z_{k}\in C$, there exists $x_{k}, y_{k}$, which have closed-form expressions using only rational numbers and no more than $(m - 1)$ times of allowed operations, such that $z_{k} = x_{k} \bullet y_{k}$ (where $\bullet$ is the last operation, which is either addition or multiplication). By the inductive hypothesis, there is a list of fields $F_{0}, F_{1}, \ldots, F_{n}$ such that $x_{1}, y_{1}, \ldots, x_{\left\vert C\right\vert}, y_{\left\vert C\right\vert}$ are in $F_{n}$. Hence $z_{1}, \ldots, z_{\left\vert C\right\vert} \in F_{n}$, according to the closure of addition and multiplication.
Case 2. There exists an element of $C$ of which last operation is square root.
Let $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{p}$ be the elements of $C$ of which the last operations are square root. Let $y_{i} = x_{i}^{2}$ for every $i\in \{ 1, \ldots, p \}$ then the expressions of $y_{1}, \ldots, y_{p}$ are in closed form with only rational numbers and no more than $(m - 1)$ times of allowed operations. From Case 1, we deduce that there is a list of fields $F_{0}, \ldots, F_{n}$ such that $F_{n}$ contains $C\smallsetminus \{ x_{1}, \ldots, x_{p} \}$. For every $i\in \{ 1, \ldots, p \}$, we define $F_{n + i} = \{ a + b\sqrt{y_{i}} : a, b\in F_{n + i - 1} \}$. With this construction, we conclude that $C$ is contained in $F_{n+p}$.
By the principle of mathematical induction, Q.E.D.
I proved the fine-tuned version instead of the original version because I was stuck at the inductive step when I tried to prove the original version.
